# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ':' token

Tags: c++, c, class, arduino

An error occurred when i uploaded this code to Arduino Atmega2560. This is a libary file which i have created for the .c files in my program.

The error is:
`herkulex.c:16: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ':' token`

The word 'class' is highlighted when the error appears, which is in the file (code shown below)

```
#ifndef herkulex_lib
#define herkulex_lib

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h> 
#include<inttypes.h> 

class herkulex
{
  public: 
    herkulex();
    void hklx_Init(unsigned long ulBaudRate);
    void hklx_SendPacket(DrsPacket stPacket);
    unsigned char hklx_ucReceivePacket(DrsPacket *pstPacket);
    void hklx_RemoveInvalidData(void);

//no private  
};

#endif /* HERKULEX_H_ */
```

May I know what's wrong with this code? Thanks!

Comment: Problem with adding .cc files into arduino. the above file was been converted to .cc file but when i tried to add a file into arduino, it doesnt show them in the tabs and i think the c++ files are not added into arduino. why is this so?

Answer (score 6):

You are compiling a C file which contains C++. The C compiler is rejecting C++ syntax.

Compile it as a C++ program instead.

Comment: may i know how i can convert this file to c++?

Comment: @shannon often, you would just change the extension to `cpp`. depending on how your build is setup, that may not work. try it.

Comment: For a start, rename the file to cpp. And then look in you IDE/Compiler for the C++ flag.

Comment: where do i find the IDE/Compiler? is it from Arduino or visual c++ program?

Comment: @shannon I think the Arduino IDE does it automatically, just rename the file, open it again with the CPP extension, and you're set

Comment: how do i change the extension to cpp? not sure if i did it correctly, i added .cpp to the back of the filename. but the file remains as .c file

Comment: ok i managed to change it to a c++ file. but when i tried to add a file into arduino, it doesnt show it in the tabs and i think the c++ files are not added

Comment: @shannon i'm sorry, i can help with c and c++, but i can't help with arduino (never used it!).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there a `space` missing here:?

```
#include<inttypes.h>
```